# Implement variable in node confirmation popup

Tags: 8

I want to add a confirmation popup for node form.
The message should be changed dynamically.

The code below worked fine in form_alter.

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['onclick'] = 'if(!confirm("Really Save?")){return false;}';
```

But the popup didn't show up if I include a variable in the code like this:

```
$text = "Really save?";
$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['onclick'] = 'if(!confirm({$text})){return false;}';
```

Is there any way to change the text dynamically?

Comment: `{$text}` is not valid syntax, try with just `$test`

Comment: `$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['onclick'] = "if(!confirm($text)){return false;}";`  didn't work as well...

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is a plain PHP and JavaScript question, not a question that needs Drupal expertise to answer it. PHP doesn't replace `$text` when the literal string is delimited from single quotes. In `"if(!confirm($text)){return false;}";` the string delimiters are correct, but `if(!confirm(Really save?)){return false;}` isn't correct JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

It works!

```
$text = "Really save?";
$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['onclick'] = 'if(!confirm("' . $text .'")){return false;}';
```